# How to use class methods from another .py file?

Tags: python, import

Following is the file structure all are in same folder:

`__init__.py
gnewsclient.py
test.py`

1)
`__init__.py:`

`from .gnewsclient import gnewsclient`

2) `gnewsclient.py`

`class gnewsclient:
      //Some methods`

Now I want to import methods from gnewsclient class of `gnewsclient.py` file inside `test.py`

I tried `from gnewsclient import *` but it says parent module not loaded '' cannot perform relative import.

Comment: Had you read [relative import in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: @You'reawesome But here I have all files in same directory

Comment: @You'reawesome Can you tell me what edits should be done.

Comment: I'm not sure but have you try this `from .gnewsclient import *`

Comment: @You'reawesome Does not work

Comment: I checked and it worked, can you give me your command when execute file test.py

Comment: @You'reawesome https://imgur.com/a/GfOf7

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems like you also have a `utils.py` modules that is used in `gnewsclient.py`. Where is it?

Comment: utils.py is also in same folder

Comment: @j_4321  I am importing util.py and gnewclient.py inside test.py but gnewsclient imports util.py inside it and all .py files are in same folder.

Comment: Do you use `test.py` just to test that your code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package layout:

```
 package
    | __init__.py
    | module1.py
    | module2.py

 script.py
```

If you want to import a function `f1` from `module1` in `module2` do: 
`from package.module1 import f1`.

Now, if you try to execute `module2.py` by doing `python module2.py`, it won't work because you are inside the package, so python does not find the path to the module and you will have the kind of error you got. So if you want to use or test your modules, you need to do it from  outside the package, in `script.py` for instance:

Example of `script.py`:

```
from package.module1 import f1
from package.module2 import f2

print(f1())
print(f2())
```

Comment: I could not understand why from package.module1 and why not from module1 as I am running test.py which is in same folder that of all other .py files

Comment: Utils.py is imported by gnewsclient.py and also by test.py so it is imported twice does that throw error.

Comment: @Icefire if there is no "loop" import (like import module1 in module2 and module2 in module1) duplicate imports don't throw errors.

Comment: No I am asking module 3 inside module 2 and also inside module 1 and in test.py we call module 3&1 will it cause error I think I have done it like this.

Comment: @Icefire No, I don't think so

Comment: check this -> https://imgur.com/a/evsDN       https://imgur.com/a/34lf8

Comment: @Icefire you need to run `test.py` from outside the package: go to `KWOC gnewsclient\gnewsclient` in the python console (not in `KWOC gnewsclient\gnewsclient\gnewsclient`) and import `gnewsclient.test`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161182/discussion-between-j-4321-and-ice-fire).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816812/how-to-add-scrollbar-for-user-defined-canvas-class-tkinter